# What does NPV ASSENTED after stock name mean?

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies, index, european, investing

For a project, I have to quantitatively implement a strategy for value investing in EURO STOXX 50. I pulled the data from Datastream. When I was checking some data plots for dividend yields and total returns, I noticed there is two times Deutsche Boerse . One is named "Deutsche Boerse" and the other "Deutsche Boerse NPV ASSENTED". "Deutsche Boerse NPV ASSENTED" has a dividend yield of 0 and I have only data for 2011 and 2012, but for "Deusche Boerse" I have data from 2001 to 2014. Also, the total returns differ in the years where I have data for both.

If you click [here](http://deutsche-boerse.com/dbg/dispatch/en/kir/dbg_nav/investor_relations/20_The_Share/45_Share_Buy_Back), you come to the website of Deutsche Boerse. It says there was an repurchase at this time. So, did they just repurchase it and did not pay dividend on the repurchased shares because they owned them? But how could this explain the difference in total returns?

I really need a clear answer because I am new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Google: NPV stock

Then google: assented stock

They are separate qualifiers. Looking for both at the same time may result in no useful answer.

Comment: So, does this somehow explain the described differences in total returns and dividend yields?

Comment: It doesn't seem to explain it, but I am not sure since I'm also new to this. I would create another question specifically to address this difference in total returns and dividend yields.

Comment: Please consider improving your answer by giving more details about your own research. Refer http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.